# Find max and min RGB values of a pixel using PIL

Tags: python

I have a basic algorithm for desaturating an image using the pillow library and Python 3:
- find max of a pixel's RGB values
- find min of a pixel's RGB values
- calc average: (max + min) / 2

How do I find the min and max red, green and blue values for each pixel? I'm completely confused! I tried this code as part of a for loop

```
 red = image.getextrema()
 green = image.getextrema()
 blue = image.getextrema()

 average = int( (red + green + blue) / 2 )
```

but the error returned is

"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'int'"

The same error msg appeared when I removed the int() function.

Not sure if I'm barking up the wrong tree completely or only slightly off the trail. Complete novice with the pillow library and just wanting to experiment with different effects.

Comment: `red` `green` `blue` are tuple, meaning `red = (min_red,max_red)`
you have to compute the average for each color: `average_red = (red[0]+red[1])/2`

Answer (score 8):

`img.getextrema()` returns the tuple of `(min_value, max_value)`. In order to get the average value, you have to do:

```
value = img.getextrema()
avg = sum(value)/len(value) # OR, sum(value)/2, as len will always be 2
```